# Guardar arreglos multidimensionales en varias filas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hola quiero guardar este arreglo en las filas que toque.

```
array:2 [
  0 => {#1259
    +"id": "genero"
    +"variaciones": array:1 [
      0 => "hombre"
    ]
  }
  1 => {#1258
    +"id": "colores"
    +"variaciones": array:3 [
      0 => "negro"
      1 => "rojo"
      2 => "blanco"
    ]
  }
]
```

Intento de este modo si éxito:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['tipos']);
foreach($data as $item){
        $variaciones = new Variation;
        $variaciones->product_id = '1';
        $variaciones->variant = $item->id;
        foreach($item->variaciones as $item2){
            $variaciones->valor = $item2;
        }
        
        $variaciones->save();
    }
```

Realmente este arreglo me lo tiene que guardar así:

```
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
| id | product_id | variant  | value     |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1          | genero   | hombre    |
| 2  | 1          | color    | negro     |
| 3  | 1          | color    | rojo      |
| 4  | 1          | color    | blanco    |   
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Solo me sta grabando; genero "hombre", color "blanco":

```
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
| id | product_id | variant  | value     |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1          | genero   | hombre    |
| 2  | 1          | color    | blanco    |   
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
```

**Muestra del var_dump($_POST)**

```
array(1) {
  ["tipos"]=>
  string(90) "[
                {"id":"genero","variaciones":["hombre"]},
                {"id":"colores","variaciones":["negro","rojo","blanco"]}
              ]
             "
}
```

Para que entendais, esto son los datos que recibo de unos selects creados con JavaSript. Entonces hago una función recursiva y luego genero unas permutaciones.

```
function generacion_recursiva(tipos, nivel, raiz) {
        if (nivel >= tipos.length - 1) {
        /* Agregamos a cada elemento su nombre separado por un punto */
            return tipos[nivel].variaciones.map(x => [ raiz, x ].join("."));
        }
    let resultados = [];
    tipos[nivel].variaciones.forEach(elemento => {
        generacion_recursiva(tipos, nivel + 1, [ raiz, elemento ].join(".")).forEach(elemento => {
            resultados.push(elemento);
        });
    });
    return resultados;
    }

$("#guarTT").click(() => {
   let selects = $('.variaciones');
   let tipos = [];
   selects.each(function (indice) {
   // Agregamos un elemento por select encontrado
   tipos[indice] = {
   id: $(this).attr('id'),
   variaciones: $(this).val() || []
   };
   });
    console.log(tipos);
   // Generamos las permutaciones
   var permutas = generacion_recursiva(tipos, 0, 'permutacion');
   console.log(permutas);

});
```

Y en el AJAX lo envio así:

```
data: {'tipos': JSON.stringify(tipos)}
```

Comment: No entiendo mucho lo que quieres hacer. `$_POST` es en sí un array, ¿parecería que lo estás leyendo para crear otro array con el array que ya es `$_POST`?

Comment: Estoy enviando algo que genero por AJAX, la variable de JavaScript que envio al controlador con la info es así: `data: {'tipos': JSON.stringify(tipos) }` @A.Cedano

Comment: Muestra un `var_dump($_POST);` para ver qué es lo que estás mandando realmente. Y como idea, ¿no podrías organizar en el cliente (Javascript/Ajax)  el objeto con la estructura que necesitas en el servidor? Lo digo para descargar lo más posible al servidor.  Por ejemplo si necesitas un array de objetos del tipo `Variation`, podrias enviar desde el cliente un array de JSON de esos objetos que luego podrías mapear/convertir fácilmente en el servidor. Si trabajas con Laravel u otro framework conviene que lo indiques.

Comment: Hola. ¿Verificaste estar recibiendo los tres colores enviados? Has un `var_dump($data);`

Comment: Ya hice el var_dump @A.Cedano lo publique al final de mi pregunta , si estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.8

Comment: Hola @quevedo lo acabo de hacer de POST, lo he puesto al final de mi pregunta

Comment: He identado el `var_dump`. Si observas, no tienes en el `$_POST` los datos que esperas. Debes revisar qué está ocurriendo del lado del cliente.

Comment: El problema está en la primera instrucción. json_decode() tiene como segundo parámetro opcional FALSE por defecto y necesitas TRUE para que se convierta en array asociativo. Ver [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php). Por esa razón no lees los items interiores

Comment: Añadi más código a la pregunta para que entiendas que hago @A.Cedano

Comment: Edite la pregunta añadiendo más código @quevedo

Comment: Dado que no conocemos el contexto y sería complicado conocerlo, por lo que veo en tu nuevo código, simplemente debes asegurarte de que el cliente produzca los datos que espera el servidor. En el var_dump no parece ser así, entonces tienes que revisar tu código del cliente para ver por qué los datos se mandan incompletos. Por ejemplo, de `hombre` no hay nada en el resultado del `var_dump`. Según sugerí en otro comentario, ¿por qué no trabajas el código en el cliente para que te produzca la estructura que esperas manejar en el servidor?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano , perdona cuando te puse lo que manda `var_dump` no hice la misma prueba con los mismo valores de la pregunta, voy a hacerlo con los mismos valores que la pregunta y modifico la pregunta, ya que eso generara confusión

Comment: Acabo de hacer un debug a tu $_POST y encontré un par de detalles que te van a sorprender en la respuesta que te anexo:

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano acabo de modificar el var_dump con los mismo valores que pongo en el pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola te recomendé usar TRUE como segundo parámetro, porque cabía esperar que variaciones fuese reconstruido como array no como stdClass. Hice un test con los valores de $_POST que publicaste inicialmente y, efectivamente, variaciones no es reconstruido como objeto si no como array:

```
<?php
$entra = '[{"id":"genero","variaciones":["mujer"]},{"id":"colores","variaciones":["rojo","blanco"]}]';
$jsonobj = json_decode($entra);
var_dump($jsonobj);
// Salida devuelta por var_dump para
object(stdClass)#8 (2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(6) "genero"
  ["variaciones"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "mujer"
  }
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#11 (2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(7) "colores"
  ["variaciones"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "rojo"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "blanco"
  }
}
```

Eso demuestra que está accesando mal los valores situados bajo variaciones `$variaciones->valor = $item->variaciones;` te entrega un array, te hace falta recorrerlo.
**Adicionalmente** Cuando tratas de recorrer varaciones `$item->variaciones as $item2` no utilizas $item2.

Analizando tu código el objeto json recibido debiera recorrerse así:

```
<php
$data = json_decode($_POST['tipos']);
foreach($data as $item){
    foreach($item->variaciones as $item2){
        // Muevo la creación de objetos a este punto porque se
        // debe recorrer el array de variaciones
        $variaciones = new Variation;
        $variaciones->product_id = '1';
      // hago validación porque en la pregunta indicas querer guardar color no colores
        $variaciones->variant = ($item->id == 'colores') ? 'color' : $item->id;
        $variaciones->valor = $item2; 
        Guardo la variación       
        $variaciones->save();
    }
} 
// No me gusta el product_id pero lo dejo así para que obtengas el valor que esperas.
```

Comment: Me devuelve este error `"json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"` @quevedo

Comment: Ah!, la respuesta la preparé para tu primer modelo. No para las variaciones que hiciste al código. En el primer modelo recibías el $_POST como una cadena

Comment: Si hice un $_POST por que el compañero me lo solicito, pero el json_decode() ya lo realizaba @quevedo

Comment: Acabo de hacer una pequeña anotación en la respuesta que indica el error al recorrer el array de variaciones

Comment: Si es algo de error de tipeo, si probe con `$item2` +

Comment: No se cómo se asigne el valor dentro de la clase variaciones (imagino que haya un array interior al que se hace append) por ese motivo no incluyo en la solución algo como `$variaciones->valor = $item2` que imagino sea lo que hace falta

Comment: No se porque no hace repetición :S

Comment: Prueba a hacer var_dump a $item2, notarás que son cadenas de nombres de colores o de géneros

Comment: Voy a extender la respuesta con una sugerencia de iteración para que te des cuenta

Comment: Me llega esto haciendo un `var_dump($item2);` `string(6) "hombre" string(5) "negro" string(4) "rojo" string(6) "blanco"` @quevedo

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta ajustando el php para que refleje lo que esperabas obtener

Comment: Vale no me funciono lo tuyo pero me sirvio para saber que pasaba. Yo hacia un foreach para sarcar la columna `variant` y luego hacia otro para sacar el arreglo de opciones seleccionadas. Hay que hacer un foreach, y nada más hacerlo hacer el segundo y la columna `variant` meterla en el foreach 2 pero `$variaciones->variant = $item->id;` de este modo si hace las repeticiones como quiero, no se si me explico, voy a intentar editar tu respuesta

Comment: Te he añadido un solicitud de editar la respuesta y al final te pongo lo que funciona. Muchas gracias @quevedo

Comment: Listo ya ajuste con tu cambio ¡gracias!. Al mover el bloque del primer ciclo for se me quedó una línea en el,

Comment: Gracias a ti, ya quedo funcionando! Lo gracioso que esto ya lo habia hecho alguna vez jaja

Comment: Me alegra mucho. El tema interesante es que uno se acostumbra a pensar el json como objeto olvidando que puede contener arrays como atributos

Answer (score 1):

Leyendo un poco tu código y el de quevedo, te puedo sugerir hacerlo de esta forma, te dejo el código y tu me comentas si te es útil o falta algo:

Recorro el objeto dos veces, uno para cada nivel de array que contenta.

```html
<?php

$array = '[{"id":"genero","variaciones":["mujer"]},{"id":"colores","variaciones":["rojo","blanco"]}]';

$objetos = json_decode($array);
  
try {

    foreach ($objetos as $objeto) {
        foreach ($objeto->variaciones as $variacion) {
            Variation::create(
                 [
                    'product_id' => 1,
                    'variant' => $objeto->id,
                    'value'   => $variacion
                 ]
            );
        }
    }
        return true;

} catch (\Throwable $th) {

        return $th->getMessage();
}
```

**El registro que se realiza en la base de datos:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código que pones es perfecto también! Quizás más limpio, marque ya la otra respuesta como correcta, pero viene perfecto para otra persona que lo necesite. Gracias por tu aportación

Comment: Un gusto que te  gustara, saludos.

Comment: Simple curiosidad,  por que manejas los registros como si fuesen campos de una tabla?

Comment: No se si te entendi bien, son campos para guardar en una tabla y con ellos luego tengo que permutarlos para guardarlos en otra tabla. Al final lo que estoy construyendo es para poder crear productos con distintas variaciones, no se si aclara eso tu duda, gracias!

Comment: Lo que te quiero decir es porque no creaste un campo con el nombre genero y ahi guardas por ejemplo mujer y otro campo con el nombre color y ahí guardas el color.

Comment: Esa era la primera alternativa, pero quiero que sea dinámico, si luego añaden un campo mas para las variaciones, se quedaría nulo lo hecho. La idea es que después de esto al darle a un botón se generen todas la variaciones automáticas